# python find columns whose values are approximately some values in a csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file which looks like the following:

```
coord,score    
0.09,1.0
0.21,0.8
0.30,0.7
0.39,0.9
```

where the 1st column represents coordinates in float, and the 2nd some kind of score. I wonder if there is good way to retrieve the above scores at specified coordinates, say [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]. Notice that there is some kind of fuzzy matching at the coordinates here. We can assume such coordinates are always valid.

Is there any python or pandas method capable of achieving this? 
some code snippets would be helpful. Thanks!

UPDATE: could do this manually by checking 'coord' against the expected coordinates, but wonder if there is any python/pandas function doing so.

Comment: You could create a dictionary of `coord` to `score`, then sort the keys and do a search (binary for efficiency, linear if you don't care) through them for the closest coordinate to the one you're looking for.

Comment: when you iterate through the scores you can instead of checking the actual coordinate, check for `abs(inputCoord - actualCoord)` and set an error margin lets say `0.02` that will catch coordinates `0.02` above or below the input coordinate

Comment: You're talking about [interpolation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#interpolation).

Comment: Thanks guys! I know exactly how to do this manually :-), just curious if any existing python/pandas method could do this.

Comment: you can aproximate a function with some machine learning model, use your current data for training and then every time you ask for a score, call the prediction from the model. check for [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) as is a pretty good tool for this and is quite easy to implement.

Comment: Do you always want to produce one of the values from the `score` column or do you want to interpolate between them? For example, given your sample file, what should the result be for the coordinate 0.10 - should it be 0.98 or 1.0 or something else? If you have code to do this manually, showing that code in the question would be quite helpful.

Comment: i wanted to have exact scores, not interpolation between two adjacent rows. for coordinate 0.10, i expected score=1.0

Comment: Should you always get the closest value, or what should happen if you are almost in the middle of two values? Or will that not happen? If there is a straight-forward way to describe how it is done, it is probably not too hard to do as a Python program.